# Como conseguir valor de um checkbox

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

Quando faço a submissão do formulário o `input` não retorna o valor da `checkbox` e diz que o `$_POST['newsconf']` não existe.

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="newsconf" name="newsconf" value="1"/>
<label for="newsconf">Assinar newsletter</label>
```

O que estou a fazer de errado para não estar a obter o valor da `checkbox`?

Comment: Acontece o mesmo se o `checkbox` está marcado ou não?

Comment: sim, acontece o mesmo

Comment: Seria bom colocar o `form` e um mínimo do *script* PHP para ver se o problema não está em outro lugar.

Comment: `$_POST['newsconf']` só vai existir se o checkbox for marcado, use `isset` para saber ele foi ou não marcado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz um teste e funcionou como devia. Você fez uma afirmação no comentário que não acredito que esteja acontecendo de fato:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="newsconf"  name="newsconf" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newsconf']) && $_POST['newsconf'] == '1') {
    echo "checkado";
} else {
    echo "não checkado";
}     
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/GetCheckboes.php).

Quando o campo não está marcado ele não é enviado pelo formulário, portanto precisa verificar se ele existe para saber se está marcado.

Caso não seja isto, não tem como saber qual é o problema com o que foi colocado na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Como complemento, uma outra solução que visa garantir que o formulário nos vai enviar sempre um valor para a `checkbox` quer a mesma se encontre marcada ou não, passa por aplicar um `input` escondido no formulário para nos fornecer um valor por defeito:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="newsconf" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="newsconf" id="newsconf" value="1" />
```

Desta forma, no PHP temos sempre a entrada na matriz que corresponde ao método de submissão do formulário, em baixo um exemplo para `method="POST"`:

```php
$querNewsletter = $_POST["newsconf"]; // vai otber 0 se não marcou ou 1 se marcou
```

---

**Notas:** Para que funcione conforme em cima descrito existem duas atenções a ter:

1. O campo escondido tem que estar antes do campo que o utilizador usa, para que o campo do utilizador subscreva o valor do campo escondido caso o utilizador efetivamente marque a `checkbox`.
2. O campo escondido tem que ter o valor no atributo `name` igual ao que usamos na `checkbox`.